# Как поменять местами 2 jPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

Итак, я создал новый jFrame, и в нем у меня есть 2 jPanel - jPanel1 и jPanel2 (как на картинке).

Мне надо поменять эти 2 jPanels местами, первая идет на место второй, а вторая на место первой (со всем, что будет внутри jPanels).

Как лучше всего это сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Посмотрите тут: https://overcoder.net/q/133846/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-jpanel-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8-jframe-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%83 сохраните ссылки и вставляйте. Можете все это вынести в отдельный метод.

Comment: @MarkCain, оригинал: https://stackoverflow.com/q/218155/4928642. Зачем даёшь ссылку на гуглоперевод с кучей рекламы?

Comment: @MarkCain, кстати, тут не сказано, что поменять надо в рантайме.

Comment: может flow layout подойдет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.awt.*;  
import javax.swing.*;  
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class PanelExample {
  // вспомогательный класс 
  private class SPanel {
    JPanel panel;
  }

  private JPanel getPanel(String caption, SPanel spanel){
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));  
    JButton button = new JButton(caption);     
    button.setBounds(0,0,40,20);    
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){  
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){  
         Rectangle oldBounds = panel.getBounds();
         // используем ссылку из замыкания
         panel.setBounds(spanel.panel.getBounds());   
         spanel.panel.setBounds(oldBounds);
      }
    });  
    panel.add(button);
    return panel;
  }
  
  PanelExample(){  
    SPanel sp1 = new SPanel(), sp2 = new SPanel();

    JFrame f = new JFrame("Panel Example");    
    JPanel p1 = this.getPanel("panel1", sp2);
    JPanel p2 = this.getPanel("panel2", sp1);
    
    // инициализируем ссылки
    sp1.panel = p1;
    sp2.panel = p2;

    // начальные позиции
    p1.setBounds(50,80,50,200); 
    p2.setBounds(105,80,50,200);        

    f.add(p1);  
    f.add(p2);  
    f.setSize(400,400);    
    f.setLayout(null);    
    f.setVisible(true);    
  }  

  public static void main(String args[]){  
    new PanelExample();  
  }   
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, это лучшее решение